# How to know when an object 3d position has been changed by user?

Tags: three.js

Per title, currently it doesn't seem obvious there is a way to know when user has finished changing position of an object in a scene.

Would be nice if there could be some clarification around the way of doing this

Edit:

What I want to know is if there is a list of events that can be used to know when something has happened. I.e: an object position has been changed, via some operation, i.e drag. There is an example of a drag operation at https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes but the example doesn't show how to detect what object has been dragged when the `dragend` event fires. Also listening to `dragend` event on a group listener like controls doesn't seem to be ideal, shouldn't individual objects also have a mechanism to notify outsiders?

Comment: Would be nice to know how you determine when an object has been changed in general?

Comment: Without constantly polling its property or turning its properties into reactive properties? When someone interacts with an object in a scene, and drag it elsewhere.

Comment: Someone will interact with objects via mouse or touches, thus, you can add listeners for respective events.

Comment: Like @prisoner849 says, objects in three.js do not move on their own, *your code* is moving them somewhere. That code also knows when it is -done- moving the objects. None of this seems the responsibility of three.js, the rendering engine. If you have a more complex case than this, please elaborate.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope it helps clarify my question.